# Screen looks like it's sinking due to weird collision/jumping values that affect camera movement

Tags: python, pygame, camera

I'm trying to implement vertical camera movement in my PyGame platformer (horizontal camera movement works fine, almost definitely irrelevant to this) but the screen always appears to constantly be sinking unless the player jumps (but when the player finishes his jump, it starts sinking again). Here's the code:

```
if self.onGround == False: # falling
        self.vermo += 0.4 # player's vertical momentum increasing as he falls
        
    if self.onGround == True:
        self.jump = False
        self.fall = False
        
    if self.vermo > 10: # can't fall too fast
        self.vermo = 10
        
    if self.vermo > 0 and self.collideWithBlock == False: # checks if the player is not on the ground but has also past climax/zenith of jump
        self.fall = True
        
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and self.onGround == True: # makes player jump but only if touching the ground
        self.vermo = -12
        self.jump = True
        
    if self.fall == True and self.onGround == False: # if the player is not on the ground but has past the climax.zenith of his jump, the camera should follow the player downward
    
        for sprite in self.game.all_sprites: # this moves every sprite on the screen to give the illusion of camera movement
            sprite.rect.y -= self.vermo
            
    if self.jump == True: # if the player is shooting upwards (jumping) then the camera should follow him upward
    
        for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
            sprite.rect.y -= self.vermo # I thought this should be += but apparently not
```

The reason this is happening is due to self.vermo looping the values below. The problem is, I have no idea what causes this.

These are the values:

0

0.4

0.8

1.2000000000000002

0

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic code for a camera class:

```
class Camera():
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.camera = pg.Rect(0,0,width,height)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def apply(self,entity):
        return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        x = -target.rect.x + width//2
        y = -target.rect.y + height//2

        x = min(0, x)
        y = min(0, y)
        x = max(-(self.width - width), x)
        y = max(-(self.height - height), y)
        self.camera = pg.Rect(x,y,self.width,self.height)
```

Every time you update, you have to apply the update method, with target=player.
This will adjust the camera according the player's new position.

```
def update(self):
    self.all_sprites.update()
    self.camera.update(self.player)
```

When you blit the other objects to the screen, you create the illusion the player is moving.

```
for sprite in self.all_sprites:
    self.screen.blit(sprite.image, self.camera.apply(sprite))
```

Keep in mind that the width and height parameters passed into the camera constructor are the width and height of the level, not the width and height of the screen.

I would try implementing this and see if it fixes your sinking problem.

You could also try adding this to your existing code:

```
if self.onGround == True:
    self.vermo = 0
    self.jump = False
    self.fall = False
```

This will ensure that when the player is on the ground, no vertical momentum.

Comment: Thank you for this! Although this camera code is highly practical, it would require rewriting a lot of my codebase. I tried your second suggestion which didn't work but the good news is now I know why. I'll post the answer in a moment. I'm still having other issues but I know why they're happening and I'm brainstorming ways of solving them.

Comment: I've come to realize that my current camera system is inefficient, with the way I need to fix other errors with it. I'm currently trying to implement your camera class but I'm unsure what pg is supposed to be, as it's not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I really couldn't tell you why, but in this line of code:

```
if self.vermo > 0 and self.collideWithBlock == False:
    self.fall = True
```

the 0 needs to be replaced with 1.6. Again, no idea why, but it works. I don't question the ways of the Python gods, but by all means if you know why this is I encourage you to comment it here.

The camera, as it is now, still has some issues, but I know why these issues are occurring and I'm currently working on fixing them.

Comment: Some other things I notice.

When you set self.fall = True, you then perform a check in a subsequent block, if self.fall == True.  You may want to consider adding some break statements so that you aren't modifying and the accessing variables within the same iteration.